# Ruby On Rails: make text field non-editable and display another field while editing a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field

1.How can i make a text field non-editable (readable=false) while editing record

My Form View Code

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label t :profile_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :profile_name %>
  </div>
```

2.How can i make a field visible while editing a record. I have a field in the database table that i just want to display to fill in while editing the record however while create a new record that field not be visible.

**RESOLVED:**

Never Mind Guys i got the solution,

```
1. 
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label t :profile_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :profile_name, :readonly => f.object.persisted? %>
</div>

2. 
<% if f.object.persisted?%>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label t :another_field %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :another_field%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: why can't you post some code to get more response?

Comment: added, but still i don't know how to put some condition in the form to check if this an edit mode then make this field non-editable

Comment: and post your condition to enable the text box to edit

Answer (score 7):

If you want your textbox to non-editable, you can do with little css or in the front end like the following:

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label t :profile_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :profile_name, disabled: disabled %>
 </div>
```

or add `:readonly => true` instead of `disabled`. so,

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label t :profile_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :profile_name, readonly: true %>
 </div>
```

Add disabled in your view to make a non-editable text box. We can do in css as well if its not work. Just let me know if its worked or not.

Comment: Your question should be clear. Before post the question just make sure what you gonna post. Thanks

Comment: My question is much clear as i said i want to do those things while editing the record.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for those who find this. My problem was very close. I had a field I wanted to display, but not have editable. I was using devise, and only allow email and password to be set via devise view.

1) Disable editing in the form (this step provides zero security):

```
<%= f.text_field :email, readonly: true %>
```

2) Prevent shenanigans on by the client (this step is the actual protection):

```
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      # params.require(:user).permit(:email, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
      # email and password must be edited via devise controller
      params.require(:user).permit(:phone_number)
    end
```

2b) Alternatively, you could just remove the value from the edit set:

```
def update
  params['user'].delete('email')
  ...
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer - how do you initially set the email via the form (via from the def new action) if you stop the email attribute from being mass assigned?