# Rails readonly date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, view, helper

In my edit action, I don't want the date to be editable, but I still want the date to be visible. Is it possible to make the `date_select` readonly while its value is still passed along with other params. I have tried `:disable => true`, but this way the date value is not passed along, and I need that value.

```
<%= f.date_select :date %>
```

Comment: You could try the [:readonly parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830223/ruby-on-rails-make-text-field-non-editable-and-display-another-field-while-edit) and see how you get on. Hope that helps!

Comment: @hd1 doesn't work on date_select

Comment: @SperanskyDanil I haven't really study much js, but if there are no other solutions I might have to look into that.

Comment: Would [overriding the accessor](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/04/20/overriding-rails-activerecord-object-fields/) sort you? In your model, define a method `def date=(aDate) self.date = Date.now end` and eliminate the line from your view.

Comment: @hd1 Sorry, but I don't really understand your method. But the reason I need the date is because the model I'm editing is an mongoid embedded document, and I need that date to find it's parent before I could edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With JavaScript:**

In views:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :disabled => true %>
```

In assets:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
  $('select').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

**With CofeeScript:**

In views:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :disabled => true %>
```

In assets:

```
$('form').submit ->
  $('select').attr('disabled', false)
```

Comment: @SperanskyDanil I see what you did there. I tried to convert it to coffeescript `$('form').submit ->
  $('select').attr('disabled', false)
` like so, and put into asset, but it doesn't work. Not sure why though. I have yet to use js in rails. Thanks for the help

Comment: @SperanskyDanil suddenly it works! not sure why lol. Thanks a lot.